# pika dropping basic_publish messages sporadically

Tags: rabbitmq, celery, pika

I'm trying to publish messages with pika, using Celery tasks.

```
from celery import shared_task
from django.conf import settings
import json

@shared_task
def publish_message():
    params = pika.URLParameters(settings.BROKER_URL + '?' + 'socket_timeout=10&' + 'connection_attempts=2')
    conn = pika.BlockingConnection(parameters=params)
    channel = conn.channel()
    channel.exchange_declare(
                exchange = 'foo',
                type='topic'
            )
    channel.tx_select()
    channel.basic_publish(
                exchange = 'foo',
                routing_key = 'bar',
                body = json.dumps({'foo':'bar'}),
                properties = pika.BasicProperties(content_type='application/json')
            )
    channel.tx_commit()
    conn.close()
```

This task is called from the views.

Due to some weird reason, sometimes randomly, the messages are not getting queued. In my case, every second message is getting dropped. What am I missing here?

Comment: why are you using  `exchange_declare` ?

Comment: I don't need to declare an exchange to send a message? Does that affect this?

Comment: did you want to simply put `json.dumps({'foo':'bar'})` into queue `foo` ?

Comment: Yes. I removed `exchange_declare`. Everything works. But messages are still getting dropped.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend that you enable [confirm_delivery](http://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html) in pika. This will ensure that messages get delivered properly, and if for some reason the message could not be delivered. Pika will fail with either an exception, or return False.

```
channel.confirm_delivery()
successful = channel.basic_publish(...)
```

If the process fails you can try to send the message again, or log the error message from the exception so that you can act accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
chanel = conn.channel()
try:
    chanel.queue_declare(queue='foo')
except:
    pass

chanel.basic_publish(
    exchange='',
    routing_key='foo',
    body=json.dumps({'foo':'bar'})
)
```